# F# idiomatic Try Until

Tags: error-handling, f#

I have a function that takes an input and either succeeds and returns Some of the input or returns None. I'll make the example a list of phone numbers that get dialed until someone answers one of the numbers, and then the rest of the numbers should be skipped. And at the end there is a logging of a successful number or of an error message.

My first solution I think is too complicated and also uses a seeding of the failure state on the first try, which seems inelegant:

```
type PhoneNumber = int

let tryCallNumber phoneNumber = 
    if phoneNumber % 2 = 0 then Some phoneNumber
    else None

let nextCall phoneNumberOption nextNumber = 
    match phoneNumberOption with
    | Some num -> phoneNumberOption
    | None     -> tryCallNumber nextNumber

let logCall phoneNumberOption = 
    match phoneNumberOption with
    | Some num -> printfn "%i" num
    | None     -> printfn "%s" "failed"


let phoneNumbers = [111; 222; 444; 555]

do List.fold (fun state num -> (nextCall state num)) None phoneNumbers
|> logCall
```

I tightened it up with a better List function, tryPick:

```
type PhoneNumber = int

let tryCallNumber phoneNumber = 
    if phoneNumber % 2 = 0 then Some phoneNumber
    else None

let logCall phoneNumberOption = 
    match phoneNumberOption with
    | Some num -> printfn "%i" num
    | None     -> printfn "%s" "failed"


let phoneNumbers = [111; 222; 444; 555]

do List.tryPick (fun num -> tryCallNumber num) phoneNumbers
|> logCall
```

Does this seem like a good approach? After reading about monadic error handling, I wonder if I should be doing something somehow more in that spirit.

Comment: Your solution using `List.tryPick` looks exactly like the code I would write...

Comment: Thanks Tomas. Appreciate your reply.

Comment: The lambda passed to `List.tryPick` can be replaced with just `tryCallNumber`

Comment: Monadic is useful for simplifying multiple layers of `match xOpt with Some x -> ... | None -> None`.  For something simple like this, your proposed solution is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idiomaticity is difficult to measure. I think your approach is close-to-most-idiomatic. And you've got Tomas' sign-off... I would add the `function` shortcut for `logCall`, drop the `do`, pipe `phoneNumbers` in, eta-reduce the `tryCallNumber` lambda:

```
let phoneNumbers = [111; 222; 444; 555]

let tryCallNumber phoneNumber = 
    if phoneNumber % 2 = 0 then Some phoneNumber
    else None

let logCall = function
| Some num -> printfn "%i" num
| None     -> printfn "failed"

phoneNumbers
|> List.tryPick tryCallNumber
|> logCall
```

*Personally* (unfortunately non-idiomatic in .NET / F# standard-lib), I'd also rename `tryCallNumber` to just `callNumber`, as IMO `option` return types are obvious enough and my code tends to be `try`-heavy and not reliant on exceptions. Similar to `async`-by-default libraries where the `...Async` suffix is dropped.

Comment: But there is a precedent in the F# standard library for a `try`-prefixed pure function to return an option - e.g. `List.tryFind` - when there is a non-prefixed counterpart that can throw an exception. So I often follow that convention too. I'm not sure `tryCallNumber` will remain pure for very long anyway. The current implementation seems like a placeholder.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox Yes, absolutely. I should have made it more clear, that this is not idiomatic (now). Hopefully this will change eventually :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This one was too easy! (But I took a roundabout route to get to it so...)  But I'll refine it a bit still from the pointers here. Thanks again.